# JavaScript - Why can the require function be used in a browser's script tag in ElectronJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, require

So in the electron-quick-start demo, there is a require function inside a HTML file `"index"` that requires Electrons render process.

I know NodeJs powers electron (and require is a node function), but when I tried to run a HTML file with simply Chrome with a require inside, it didn't work(which is expected, but i thought maybe you can only use require in the backend.

Is it because when you run electron with `"electron . "` , it interprets the HTML files differently like how react can use JSX or ruby with HTML.erb?

Comment: Does that suggest that Electron has a modified version of Chromium enabling certain proprietary functions like "require"? Cuz I thought default chromium doesn't support require either.

Answer (score 0):

Both the renderer and the main electron process have - by design - access to the require function.

This so-called node-integration sometimes interrupts proper operation of jQuery and other frontend libraries, it can be disabled via the nodeIntegration property during the `browserWindow` setup:

```
// In the main process.
  const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false
    }
  })
  win.show()
```

Be aware: this will also disable the Inter-Process Communication (IPC) library, you will no longer be able to exchange messages between the main and your respective renderer process ([there's a workaround](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron)).

Security note: NodeIntegration / require() only works as long as you reference local HTML files from within Electron. More information on security concerns related to nodeIntegration [can be found here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/security.md).

Answer (score -1):

In the demo they would be  trying to use a require tag inside of the chrome browser that's requiring a node module that's only available inside of electron.Hence its kind of working inside electron all the time which is either installed globally or is present in one of your node_modules.